# adb logcat cordova android 4

Tags: android, cordova, logging, adb

I used to log from my android phone with: **adb logcat Cordova:D DroidGap:D CordovaLog:D *:S***

This isn't working anymore, probably because of the new android update. Does anyone know how to log from the phone now?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try using this command:

```
adb logcat chromium:D SystemWebViewClient:D *:S
```

Comment: i see smilies everywhere :D :S

Comment: PowerShell way: `adb logcat | Select-String (adb shell ps | findstr your.app.id).Split("", [System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)[1]`